# Проблемы при установке и настройке SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony2, symfony3

Прочитал статью [Установка и настройка SonataAdminBundle + SonataUserBundle + FOSUserBundle](http://andrei.pahol.co/blog/ustanovka-i-nastroika-sonataadminbundle-sonatauserbundle-fosuserbundle) и решил опробовать её на деле.

Еле разобрался с первым пунктом (т.к. на момент написания блога актуальными были совсем другие версии бандлов), как на втором пункте (после редактирования файла **app/AppKernel.php**) у меня появилась ошибка:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
>     The child node "default_contexts" at path "sonata_block" must be configured.

Гуглил, смотрел ответы по этому вопросу, но они, к сожалению, либо на английском, либо на португальском языках, которыми я не владею. Помогите, пожалуйста, устранить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка значит, что в дереве конфигурации на этапе компиляции определенного бандла не нашлось значения для обязательного параметра.

Если следовать соглашениям Symfony, то скорее всего это бандл `SonataBlockBundle`. Открывая [документацию по бандлу](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/installation.html) видим, что нам нужна конфигурация этого бандла в виде:

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [sonata_page_bundle]
```

Этот код рекомендуется размещать в `app/config.yml`, но также можно разместить во всех подключаемых к нему файлах, а также в файлах конфигурации конкретного окружения (например, `app/config_dev.yml`). Пока Вы слабо знакомы с Symfony, рекомендую все подобные параметры хранить в едином файле конфигурации `app/config.yml`.